# Digits difference of numbers between 10 and 99

Tags: decimal-expansion

I was asked the question, how many numbers between 10 and 99 have digits that differ **EXACTLY** by 3?

I didn't understand the question, I thought it meant numbers like 11,44,77 then 22,55,88 and 33,66,99 but I was wrong. What does the question mean?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would interpret it as meaning that the two digits of the number differ by $3$. (The absolute value of the difference between the first digit and the second  digit is $3$.)  Examples: $41$, $30$, $58$.